# Ascending Order of Numbers By First Digit

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want an array of numbers in ascending order according to first digits using PHP.  So, for the following input array:

```
$s = array( 11, 12, 13, 18, 23, 25, 34, 114 );
```

the resulting ordered array should appear like this:

```
11 12 13 18 114 23 25 34 .. so on
```

Comment: cast the values in the array as strings, then sort it

Comment: It should sort the values lexically on the first digit, and then numerically for the rest…? I.e., it must be `11, 12, 114`, not the more typical `11, 114, 12`…? That seems… odd.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7413190/6521116)

Comment: May be your want to compare the first digit, then the remain part of the digit.

Comment: "key sort" version of the same question: [Un-naturally sort array by its numeric keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4106344/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is slightly confusing, if you want to sort naturally, it should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [7] => 114
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 13
    [3] => 18
    [4] => 23
    [5] => 25
    [6] => 34
)
```

If this is how you need, just use `sort_flags` in [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function - `SORT_STRING` that compares item as string:

```
$s = array(11,12,13,18,23,25,34,114);
sort($s, SORT_STRING);
print_r($s);
```

---

**Note:** Can you explain how you bring 114 after 18?

Comment: That is what I have posted @KrisRoofe, why do you need eval to verify?

Answer (score 1):

From the statement of SO, I think it should compare with twice compare, first for the first digit, then the remains digit.

Compare the first char of the element, then compare the remain part. You can refer to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7413190/6521116) to compare part of number.

check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/804154)**

```
<?php
$s = array(11,12,13,18,23,25,34,114);
usort($s, function($a, $b){
if(substr($a, 0, 1) < substr($b, 0, 1))
  return -1;
if(substr($a, 0, 1) > substr($b, 0, 1))
  return 1;
return substr($a, 1) - substr($b, 1);

});
print_r($s);
```

Result,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 13
    [3] => 18
    [4] => 114
    [5] => 23
    [6] => 25
    [7] => 34
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array of numbers were a bit more shuffled and included a larger value as well as duplicates, then the code should presort the array before applying usort(), as follows:

```
<?php

$s =  [ 25, 12, 23, 1006, 13, 114, 11, 34, 18, 13, 112 ];
sort($s);

$func = function($a, $b){

  $first_digitA = substr($a, 0, 1);
  $first_digitB = substr($b, 0, 1);

  if($first_digitA < $first_digitB){
    return -1;
  }
  else
  if( $first_digitA > $first_digitB ){
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
      return 0;
  }
};

usort($s, $func);

print_r($s);
```

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/Eq2qq)

After presorting by value with sort(), the resulting array looks like this:

```
[ 11, 12, 13, 13, 18, 23, 25, 34, 112, 114, 1006]
```

Now, usort() with its callback may be successfully applied, provided that the  callback takes advantage of [balanced ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary) logic, which one may recognize in PHP's strcmp(), such that "-1" denotes that the value of $a is less than that of $b, while "1" means $a is greater than $b.  If none of these choices are true, then $a must equal $b in which case the return value is zero. Thus, the comparison restricts itself to examining only the first digit of each numeric pair of values passed to the callback.

Note that the anonymous function definition appears apart from usort(), using instead $func  as a paramter since its value holds the user defined function, all for the purpose of improving legibility.